# Wordpress meta key исключение

Tags: wordpress

Как внедрить исключение в wordpress? Делаю вот так, посты находятся, но исключение по мета ключу 'class' не работает.

```
         <?php
    $class = strval(htmlspecialchars($_GET['class']));
$lang = strval(htmlspecialchars($_GET['lang'])); 
                    $posts = get_posts([
                'category' => get_queried_object()->term_id,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'meta_key' => 'class',
                'meta_value' => $class,
                'meta_key' => 'language_id',
                'meta_value' => $lang

            ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы определили свойство `meta_key` равным сначала `class`, а затем переопределили его, присвоив значение `language_id`, не надо так.

Используйте `WP_Query()` ([официальная документация](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)) и параметр `meta_query` для группировки по нескольким типам мета-данных.

```
$class = strval(htmlspecialchars($_GET['class']));
$lang = strval(htmlspecialchars($_GET['lang']));

$args = array(
    'category' => get_queried_object()->term_id,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'class',
            'value' => $class
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'language_id',
            'value' => $lang
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Стандартный цикл в таком случае будет выглядеть так:

```
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        ...
    }
}
```